# Tridion 2011 SP1 Linking service not working correctly

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, dynamic-linking

we migrated an old ASP project from 5.3 to 2011 SP1, and on one environment we cannot get the dynamic linking working.

The CD Linking has been installed as a windows service, which is running fine on the impacted server (as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493407/getting-dynamic-linking-working-on-classic-asp-pages)

All config & license files are valid and put on the right place, but the error we get is related to the cd_broker_conf.xml, while the cd_storage_conf.xml is available. See logging below for more detailed information.

Are we missing/overlooking something?

```
    2013-05-21 15:33:19,213 ERROR ASPBroker - Could not load Broker Configuration, using default values where possible. 
com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Can't find configuration file: [ cd_broker_conf.xml ] 
                at com.tridion.configuration.XMLConfigurationReader.readConfiguration(XMLConfigurationReader.java:92) ~[cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.Controller.loadConfiguration(Controller.java:404) ~[cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:116) ~[cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.broker.Broker.<init>(Broker.java:81) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.broker.ASPBroker.<init>(ASPBroker.java:51) [cd_datalayer.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.broker.ASPBroker.getInstance(ASPBroker.java:63) [cd_datalayer.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.broker.ASPBroker.main(ASPBroker.java:132) [cd_datalayer.jar:na] 
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_37] 
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_37] 
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_37] 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_37] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.runMethod(ServiceHandler.java:954) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.runStaticMethod(ServiceHandler.java:932) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.runMain(ServiceHandler.java:916) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.startServices(ServiceHandler.java:772) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.<init>(ServiceHandler.java:587) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.<init>(ServiceHandler.java:524) [cd_core.jar:na] 
                at com.tridion.jni.ServiceHandler.main(ServiceHandler.java:136) [cd_core.jar:na]
```

Comment: check the beginning of the logfile, is that indeed mentioning version 2011, because by the looks of that ASPBroker error, it is still using the 5.3 jar files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

issue resolved: on the concerned server, the default rights of the built-in IUSR (--> default user to run the website/app pool when anonymous access is allowed) were different (not sufficient) to run the CD_LINK object creation. Modifying the rights fixed the issue.